# Solving a system of linear congruences with a small mistake

Tags: number-theory

I having trouble solving the system of linear congruences:

$x \equiv 1 (mod 2)$ (a)

$x \equiv 1 (mod 3)$ (b)

so what i do is from (a)

$x = 2y + 1$

and into (b)

$2y + 1 \equiv 1 (mod 3)$

so

$2y \equiv 0 (mod 3)$

and $(2,3) = 1$, $1|0$ so a solution exists.

now I try to find a $k,y \in \mathbb{Z}$ s.t.

$2y + 3k = 1$

and I know that $3 = 2.1 + 1$

so $2(-1) + 3 = 1$ and this implies that

$y \equiv -1 (mod 3) \space$ and thus $\space y \equiv  2 (mod 3)$ so

$ y = 3l + 2, \space l \in \mathbb{Z}$ so

$x = 6l + 5$ and so $x \equiv 5 (mod 6)$ but this is not the correct answer, where am I making my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x \equiv 1(mod 2)$ gives: $x = 2k + 1$, and $x \equiv 1(mod 3)$ gives: $x = 3n + 1$. So: $2k + 1 = 3n + 1$ and $3n = 2k$. Thus $n = 2t$, and $k = 3t$. So $x = 6t + 1$, $t \in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: found the mistake, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Simpler: $\ 2,3\mid x-1\iff 2\cdot 3\mid x-1\iff x\equiv 1\pmod 6$

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, the mistake occurred with $2y + 3k = 1$ I instead need to solve $2y + 3k = 0$